# Regarding Surgery and Orientation

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, orientation, surgery-theory

Is this true for any rational homology 3-sphere Y (or any 3-manifold where $$K \subset Y$$ is null-homologous)?
$$Y_{\frac{p}{q}} (K) =  (-Y)_{- \frac{p}{q}} (m(K))$$ where m(K) is the mirror of K in -Y.

Any reference or a sketch of proof will be real helpful.

Comment: What is the mirror of a knot if the manifold is not $S^3$?

Comment: @Carl you can think of getting m(K) from K after changing all the crossings.

Comment: What crossings?  Crossings require a diagram.  And in manifolds that aren't $S^3$ you need more than Reidemeister moves to relate different diagrams of the same knot.  If the manifold is given by a surgery diagram then you'd have to show that sliding over a 2-handle and then switching all crossings gives you the same knot as if you didn't slide over the 2-handle.

Comment: I see your point. Well,to be exact, this is what I've in mind: 'you can get m(K) in -Y by reversing the orientation of Y but keeping the original orientation of K' (I'm quoting Zhongtao Wu here,as written in 'Cosmetics Surgery in L-space homology spheres')

Comment: I see, so you are assuming the existence of a canonical orientation reversing homeomorphism as with $S^3$.  Then the fact that your knot is null homologous lets you define a canonical framing for the surgery (p = number of times the surgery slope passes through the seifert surface, q = number of times it passes through a meridian).  In this case restricting your orientation reversing homeomorphism to a neighborhood of the knot should take p/q curves to -p/q curves and your result would follow, I think.

Comment: I think the most important thing is to carefully define the surgery slope in both $Y$ and $-Y$, then apply the orientation reversing homeomorphism and check how it affects the surgery slope.  If it sends $p/q$ to $-p/q$ under your definitions then it can be extended across the 2-handles to be the same manifold even after surgery.

Answer (score 0):

For an integral homology 3-sphere, your relation is very nearly the proof of Thm. 2.8.v, p. 198 in Boyer and Lines, regarding properties of their extension of Casson's invariant to homology lens spaces.  Walker [extended Casson's invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casson_invariant#Rational_homology_3-spheres) (differently) to rational homology 3-spheres.  I'm not sure how surprised I would be if a similar argument worked for this other invariant.

Boyer, Steven and Daniel Lines, Surgery formulae for Casson's invariant and extensions to homology lens spaces. J. reine angew. Math. 405 (1990), 181-220.  https://eudml.org/doc/153216

Walker, K., An extension of Casson's invariant. Annals of Mathematics Studies, 126. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1992. ISBN 0-691-08766-0, ISBN 0-691-02532-0